# Sick Lidar data with motor encoder

Tags: ros, lidar, laser, 3d-navigation, 3d-object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Autonomous Solutions has a 3D SICK Lidar - Forecast.

How would you integrate the laser data on one node and then the position data from the encoder on another node?  The sicktoolkit provides drivers for the LMS2XX are there differences for the LMS1XX and LMS5XX?

Thanks for your help,

Matt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49934/sick-lidar-data-with-motor-encoder/) by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2012-12-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2012-12-07**:
sorry but your question does not make any sense. please elaborate

**Comment by [Droter](https://answers.ros.org/users/2350/droter/) on 2012-12-10**:
Hi Brice, tried to clarify the question.  This is similar to the question http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Driver-for-any-3D-Laser-Scanner-Available-td1679151.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I think that you are asking two questions here.

The first is how do you integrate the laser data and the position data of the encoder, right? This is yet another job for TF (wiki.ros.org/tf). You can think of it like this...

If the lidar is sitting on top of a table and the encoder is set to be parallel with the table, then the transform between the laser data and the table will just be the height different between the table and the laser plane.

```
    //\\ ----lidar plane---->
    ||||
----table-----
```

When the encoder is moved to some angle (theta), then the transform is a rotation of theta and a translation of the height difference explained above. The TF tutorials will explain all of this much better but I wanted to give you a quick idea of what to expect.

Your second question about the drivers. We purchased our SICKLMS5XX from a company called Adept so I pulled their drivers and wrapped them for ROS. I can tell you that the LMS5XX driver is based on the LMS1XX driver not the LMS2XX driver (believe it or not) so I do think that there are differences between LMS2XX and the LMS5XX. I personally did not have any luck with getting the sicktoolkit stuff to work with our lidar, which is why I wrapped the other driver.

---

Originally posted by [skiesel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2807/skiesel/) with karma: 549 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0